# Select last element without a class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm dynamically adding and removing classes to and from elements on specific JS events. What I would like to do is select **the last child element that has none these classes** with CSS.

**Example #1**

```
<container-element>
  <h2></h2>
  <div class='some-class'></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> <!-- select this div -->
</container-element>
```

**Example #2**

```
<container-element>
  <h2></h2>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> <!-- select this div -->
  <div class='some-class'></div>
</container-element>
```

Is it possible to write a **CSS selector** to do this?

**Something** like `container-element > div:not(.select):last-of-type`?

Comment: @fstanis im not trying to select the last element WITH a class. im trying to select the last element WITHOUT a class.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, since the linked "last child with a specific class" is impossible in pure CSS, the same goes for this.

Comment: Specifically, I believe the workarounds presented in the other question apply here as well.

Comment: @fstanis youre 100% sure its impossible??

Comment: @fstanis isnt it possible using some sort of attribute selector like `[class~='list']:last-of-type`?

Comment: Check the discussion in that other answer - there's a lot of useful information on how that works and I believe it wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: Are there any other targetable features in your HTML? Total number of siblings? Element types?

Comment: as you said *adding and removing classes to and from elements on specific JS events.* --> so I am pretty sure you can handle this with JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif i def can, but as we talked about before: better to use CSS if possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif found a way to do it with pure HTML and CSS that is pretty darn simple. im gon post my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735782/2676845), the solution would technically be `container-element > div:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.select))`.

However, this `of S` clause in `:nth-last-child` [is still not supported by any browser other than Safari](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of).

Comment: thats an old answer tho. `nth-last-child` is def the right approach. ill be back later when the raptors game is over

Comment: How is `nth-last-child` the right approach? Still +1 to this answer because I learned about `of S`. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael_B cuz it traverses upwards/backwards thru the document

Comment: No it doesn't. It just selects the last child it finds on the way down.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying: *select the last sibling that doesn't contain a class attribute*.

I don't believe it's possible with currently available CSS.

You're asking a waterfall (the cascade) to run upward. The browser needs to check the last element, then check the ones that came before it. This is not how CSS works.

`div:not(.some-class):last-of-type` won't work because the browser doesn't move up automatically to the next sibling.

Comment: theres `nth-last-child` now tho

Comment: so there are initially 4 children, which turns into 3, once you select one of them from the dropdown since the child header is removed

Comment: i can achieve something like this with pure CSS and HTML, but id have to assign an arbitrary class to the other elements. `div:not([class*=[not-selected])` or even `div:not([class~=[not-selected])`

Comment: Yes. If you have that option, then the solution is easy.

Comment: yeah thats what im gon do

Answer (score 0):

Of course I can do this with JS, but preferred a pure CSS solution. Supposedly a pure CSS solution is not possible, so the next best thing is an CSS solution with a little extra HTML.

The trick was to add a class, `not-selected`, to all of the elements, then remove this class from the element that you want to target with the CSS selector.

And the CSS selector would be `div:not([class*='not-selected'])`.

```css
div:not([class*='not-selected']) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type='button'>
  <h2>title</h2>
  <div class='not-selected'>option one</div>
  <div>option two</div>
  <div class='not-selected'>option three</div>
</button>
```